# Add paragraph to TMemo

Tags: delphi

How can I add paragraphs of a text file separately to a Memo in Delphi?
Sue

Comment: Given TMemo's poor rich-text capabilities, paragrpaph in it equals an individual line accessible as Memo.Lines[I] (or string read by single Readln() call). To prevent guesswork give a definition of your paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

Use `TMemo.LoadFromFile` and load the entire file directly

```
Memo1.LoadFromFile(YourFileNameHere);
```

Use TStringList.LoadFromFile and add each line (including blank ones) from there

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(YourFilenameHere);
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(SL);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

// or
var
  SL: TStringList;
  s: String;
  // or i: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(YourFilenameHere);
    for s in SL do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
    // or
    // for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    //  Memo1.Lines.Add(SL[i]);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you're looking to add a new paragraph, you can just use this:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('');   // Add a blank line to separate paragraphs
```

and then use the code above to add new single lines to the memo.

Finally, if you have text in the memo and you want to add an entire block of text as a new paragraph:

```
var
  s: string;
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(YourFilenameHere, fmOpenRead);
  try
    SetLength(s, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(s[1], Stream.Size);

    // sLineBreak is in System.pas
    Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text + sLineBreak + s;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If none of these are what you want, you'll need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: Would probably be 'Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile()'. Not sure if using an additional string list would make much difference..

Comment: @Sertac: I agree, but there was the "add paragraphs..separately", which I wasn't sure how to interpret. So I provided a couple of solutions. :)

Comment: @Ken: Hi guys,
Sorry for confusion! Actually I have a loop which during the running time checks the time of experiment and compares it with specified time read from another file. Each time, according to the result of the time checking (two cases, < or >) I need to add one paragraph of a text file. So the paragraphs will be added separately as the loop goes on. I’m just going to try your answers. Thanks alot.Sue

Comment: Would whoever downvoted my answer care to explain? What did I miss or say that was wrong?

Comment: @Sue: Then my final suggestion should work; just compare the timestamp after reading from the `TStream` into the `string`, and then if need be add to the `TMemo`. You can also use the `TStringList.LoadFromFile` method, and replace the line in the `TStream` suggestion: `Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text + sLineBreak + SL.Text;`

Comment: @Ken: I am trying the TSringList.LoadFromFile method. What do I need to replace in there exactly?Thanks for your patience!Sue

Comment: @Sue: Use the second `TStringList.LoadFromFile` I gave you, and replace the `for..in` loop with: `Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text + sLineBreak + SL.Text;`, as I mentioned in my last comment.